# UML diagram based on Spring

Tags: java, spring, uml

For my school project, I need to draw a UML diagram based from my application. I built my webapp using Spring Boot and the Microservices architecture.

Which classes are required in a UML diagram? Do I include all entity classes, all services, and controllers? Or is it just the entities and services?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to ask your teacher what they expect.  This is something that strangers on the Internet really can't answer for you.

Comment: first maybe it's better to know which UML-diagram you wanted to draw ? ( structure or behavior type ?). Guessing `class diagram` so just look what are the requirements on a particular type. UML diagrams are standardize, but also it's better to check again with instructor which details should be filled (mainly all classes should be present, but it's needed to add all methods ? etc)

Comment: In short: what you think is useful to communicate the design. But, see above comments.

Answer (score 4):

There is no generally accepted documentation practice that tells what should be or not in the diagram. Moreover
you are not bound by a single diagram that shows it all.

To start with, you need to explain the goal of your application. Draw a use-case diagram to make a summary of the user goals that are addressed.

A class diagram of the domain is then always very useful. It shows the entities and how they relate, and domain services that do not belong to any single class. This allows the reader to grasp what it’s all about.

Your application design, with all the controllers, application services, and UI objects may be an overkill. A better approach is to take one example to show how controllers, services and one or two entities relate in a class diagram. Some interaction scenario in form of a sequence diagram then help to grasp the dynamics.

Finally you may use a component diagram to show  the big picture of your system. To show the overall architecture without getting lost in the many details of the underlying classes.

The best is however to ask confirmation from your client/teacher.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself: if someone gave you documentation required to write the application, what would you want to see?

- All functions on all classes.
- How classes interacted.
- Exception behavior.

I'd recommend a complete class diagram and one sequence diagram per use case.

You'll also want to tell them how to deploy each component.

What about security?  Be sure to include details about that.

What else might be useful?  Don't wait for your teacher's answer.  Try to answer it for yourself.

One more word of advice: create them using [Plant UML](https://plantuml.com/) instead of a fancy tool.  Your diagrams will be text-based and looking great.